# Cant run asp.net application on remote server when using a common connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web application . When using common connection string to call the database,it shows error in REMOTE SERVER.But runs properly on LOCAL SERVER.what to do ?

```
public class MainClass
{

public  SqlConnection getcon()
 {

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=b*****;Initial Catalog=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=**; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" );
    return con;


}
```

and the Login.aspx contains

```
 public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
MainClass obj = new MainClass();
 protected void bt_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();

  con.Open();
```

}

Comment: First of all, please display the piece of code what is going wrong. Also, add the connectionstring and replace the username and password with *** so we can check if something is wrong in there.

Comment: what error message does it show on the remote server?

Comment: Error :The type or namespace name 'MainClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume MainClass is in a class library solution.

If that's correct, please check the framework version of solutions and if the library files are existing on the remote server.

Comment: library files are existing on remote server.. even though showing same error .

Comment: also this error occurs when framework version selected as client profile. Be sure the solutions' framework is not client profile version.